# Listening for clicks only inside a div without interfering with its children (a hitbox)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, elm

I have the following DOM structure:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#content_child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content_text">Hello</div>
    <div id="content_child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`#content_text` and `#content_child` would have various mouse events. I would like to detect mouse events on `#container`. But, if I simply attach events to `#container`, they will be activated by it's children, which is not desired. My requirements are the following (I'm using click events as an example):

- when `#container` is clicked, I want its event to trigger
- when a child *graphically* located **within** its div (like `#content_text`) is clicked, I want both the child's and `#container`'s events to trigger
- when a child *graphically* located **outside** its div (like `#content_child`) is clicked, I want **only** the child's event to trigger

I know beforehand which children will be outside and inside the div.

I can think of two approaches, both quite flawed:

1. Attach mouse events to `#container`, and for each child outside the div, add events same as those attached to `#container`, but make the handlers not do anything and make them non-propagating. This gets a bit unwieldy.
2. Add a "hit area"/"hitbox" div... *somewhere*. It would be a transparent div that's a child of `#container` (and the same size) and it would register clicks, which wouldn't propagate to the children of it's siblings, namely `#content`'s children, because they are siblings. If I place it before `#content`, all of hitbox's events would be eaten by `#content` and they don't ever trigger. If I place it after, it's the same problem just the other way around. I can't have both listen for the same events at the same time in the same place, without passing them out to all their children.

Is there a way to achieve a hitbox sort of behavior without significant restructuring or fancy Javascript (I'm using Elm so both aren't an option)?

Comment: event.target and currentTarget will help you.

Comment: Do as suggested. **event.currentTarget** is reference to element to which event is attached (container in Your case), and **event.target** is reference to element which have been clicked.

You can use for example **element.match** function, to match clicked element against given css selector.

Comment: Event targets don’t care about where elements are _displayed_, but take into account DOM structure. So checking targets won’t help for the “graphically inside/outside” stuff; you will have to _calculate_ if the click happened “inside” or “outside” the element in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the handler to `#container`. When you receive the event, if it passed through a child that is *graphically* outside the container, ignore it.

You can determine the path the click took to get to the container by examining `target` on the event object, and (if necessary) its `parentNode`, and so on, until you reach container.

Here's an example (in this, I hardcoded my check of whether the child is *graphically* inside the parent, since you said you already know that; no need to go into the work of figuring it out for a simple example):

```js
function hook(selector, event, handler) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
  });
}
// container's click handler
hook("#container", "click", function(e) {
  if (passedThroughChildOutsideBox(e, this)) {
    // Ignore
  } else {
    console.log("container click");
  }
});
// child handlers
hook("#content_text, #content_child", "click", function(e) {
  console.log(this.id + " click");
});

// Fake detection
function passedThroughChildOutsideBox(e, container) {
  var node = e.target;
  while (node && node !== container) {
    if (node.id === "content_child") { // Again, just hardcoded for demo
      return true;
    }
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#content_child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content_text">Hello</div>
    <div id="content_child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Before I accept your (excellent) answer, just to make sure: is the really no way to do this without Javascript? Some arcane way to place the hitbox div such that it's behind and in front the content? Some CSS magic with `pointer-events` or `z-index`? As I've said, I'm doing this in Elm and in order to implement your solution I'd have to change some core libraries.

Comment: @user2244484: I can't think of a way to do this with CSS since you want clicks to register on the child elements. But the elm version of the above wouldn't be complicated, would it?

Comment: It would, or so I thought before I found [this library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-dom/1.2.3/DOM). That might avoid me having to write native javascript code. I haven't tried that yet, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use stop propagation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

will prevent further propagation..

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var container_text = document.getElementById("content_text");
var container_child = document.getElementById("content_child");

container.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log('this is the container');
});

container_text.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log('this is the container_text');
});
container_child.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('this is the container_child');
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#content_child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content_text">Hello</div>
    <div id="content_child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As with the other answer suggesting this, it's covered in the OP. This is my current solution, but I don't like disabling a bunch of events for every child separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try [e.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) which will block parents click while finds child event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#container").click(function(e) {
    alert("#container clicked");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("#content_text").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("#content_text clicked");
  });

  $("#content").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("#content clicked");
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#content_text {
  background: grey;
}

#content_child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content_text">Hello</div>
    <div id="content_child">hi</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZbYvp

//codepen.io/anon/pen/zZbYvp

Comment: I've said in the OP that I've tried stopping propagation and why I dislike the approach.